# How to remove black background in rendered rgba png image sequence?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, blender-internal-render-engine, image, transparency

I rendered an animation in blender cycles and I set it to the following settings:

[image: png settings]

[image: transparent checked]

I waited for hours for the image sequence to be rendered into a transparent background image sequence, and yet the result was a black background!!!

May I know what did I do wrong?

Comment: Have you tried compositing your frames on a white background?

Comment: @HISEROD No I haven't. May I know how?

Comment: There are many ways to check if your alfa channel is working. You should be able to find what you need through a quick internet search or YouTube. ;)

Comment: @HISEROD Okay I will check. But if the alpha channel is working, what do I do next. Because I rendered 72 png images so that I can create them into an image sequence in blender's video editor.

Comment: You could put a color strip beneath your frames in the VSE to check if your alfa channel is correct.

Comment: @HISEROD I added a color strip beneath the image sequence in blender's video editor but still I have the same issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131295/discussion-between-omar-osama-and-hiserod).

Comment: @HISEROD I did check whether there is an alpha channel or not. All the png images have an alpha channel

Comment: Make sure in the VSE, the image sequence which should have transparency is set to _Blend_ > _Alpha Over_ in _Compositing_, not _Cross_ or _Replace_ etc., also make sure in the _Preview_ window that _Display Channels_ is set to _Color and Alpha_, not _Color_. Have you opened an image of the sequence in a software like Photoshop etc. which can display transparency? Is the background black there, too?